# Stability of linear time varying system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, stability-theory

In the case of LTV systems, of the form

$\dot{x} = A(t)x$

the notion of uniformly globally asymptotical stability and globally exponential stability, are they one and the same? If possible, can anyone suggest any examples?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they aren't. A counterexample is the system
$$\tag{1}
\dot x=-x/t,\qquad t\in[1,+\infty).
$$
The solution to the initial value problem
$$
\dot x=-x/t,\qquad x(t_0)=x_0
$$
is given by
$$
x(t)= x_0\cdot \frac{t_0}{t}.
$$
Since $t\ge t_0$, we have $$\forall t\ge t_0\;\;|x(t)|\le|x_0|.$$
This means that the system (1) is uniformly stable by definition (one can take $\delta=\epsilon$ in the definition of uniform stability). 
But the system (1) is not exponentially stable because the reciprocal function decays slower than any function of the form $e^{-kt}$, $k>0$.